# With Django, how do I reference an existing model in a form save method instead of creating a new instance?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to use a ModelChoiceField to display options populated from model, and when a user selects a choice, store that method in a different model.

I'm using  a standard form instead of a ModelForm, because I wasn't able to get the form to display how I wanted to when using a Modelform.

My issue is that in my form save method, a new instance is created, which is not what I want.

Here are the relevant models:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254) 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    assigned_manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)    
    
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
        
        
class Manager(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manager_email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254)
    username = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)    
        
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

My view:

```
def manageclient(request, urlid):
    client = Client.objects.get(id=urlid)
    form = AssignManagerForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AssignManagerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'mysite/manageclient.html', {})
    else:
        form = AssignManagerForm()
    context = {
        'client': client,
        'urlid': urlid,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'mysite/manageclient.html', context)
```

And my forms.py

```
class AssignManagerForm(forms.Form):

    full_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Manager.objects.all())
    
    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        client = Client(assigned_manager=data['full_name'])
        client.save()
```

What I need to do is pass the urlid in my view to my save method in my forms.py, but I am unsure how to do that. Even if i could do that, I'm not sure how to modify form save to use urlid to refer to a specific record and set only the `assigned_manager` record.

Additionally, while I want the meta field to be used to display the form, I know it isn't what should be being passed to the assigned_manager field. How would I pass a Manager of instance to establish the foreign key relationship?

edit: edited to correct queryset in forms.py as per comments

Comment: Shouldn't `AssignManagerForm.full_name.queryset` be a `Manager` queryset?

Comment: @IainShelvington I don't see `AssignManagerForm.full_name.queryset` anywhere in my code?

Comment: The field `full_name` on the form `AssignManagerForm` has a `queryset` of `Client.objects.all()` but `Client.assigned_manager` is a foreign key to `Manager` not `Client`. The way you have your models and forms configured you would be assigning the wrong model to your foreign key

Comment: @IainShelvington Ah yes I got you, and you are 100% correct. That isn't actually an issue in my code, it just happened while I was posting the question. Fixed and thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: What issues do you have with using a `ModelForm`? Using one would simplify your code quite a bit

Comment: @IainShelvington I wasn't able to get my ModelChoiceField to display correct. I couldn't specify my meta field full_name in forms.py, and even without that if I just tried using one field like last_name, it displayed as a text_box instead of a select field. I spent a lot of time on it and went through other So answers, and my current solution is the only way I was able to get it to work.

Comment: You can override the label for a field in a ModelForm by passing Meta.labels https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: @IainShelvington  believe I tried that. It was still displaying a text box and not a select field. I spent a few hours on it this morning and once I got my current method working I just settled on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using a `ModelForm`, by using a `ModelForm` you no longer have to manually set attributes on save or provide initial values when updating an existing instance.

The field `assigned_manager` will still be named `assigned_manager` but it's label can be overridden to be whatever you want it to be by passing `labels` in the `ModelForm.Meta`

```
class AssignManagerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['assigned_manager']
        labels = {'assigned_manager': 'Full name'}


def manageclient(request, urlid):
    client = Client.objects.get(id=urlid)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AssignManagerForm(request.POST, instance=client)
        if form.is_valid():
            client = form.save()
            # The general convention is to redirect after a successful POST
    else:
        form = AssignManagerForm(instance=client)
    context = {
        'client': client,
        'urlid': urlid,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'mysite/manageclient.html', context)
```

Comment: Hi Iain, thanks for this, I will try it out. I've marked @ruddra answer as correct because it is specific to the question asked, but I am interested to try this solution and adopt if it works. I have one question, where is modelchoicefield defined? Also I was loading the same template after form submit because I wanted to show the same page just with the updated result.

Comment: A `ForeignKey` is automatically turned into a `ModelChoiceField` on a `ModelForm`, by passing the field name of the `ForeignKey` in the `ModelForm.Meta` this is all handled for you

Comment: Not doing anything on the line I have commented will still result in the original template being rendered as it happens outside of the `if/else`

Comment: Yes it works amazingly, thank you! Not sure how I had so much trouble with it before, you've made it seem so simple. I feel I should still set @ruddras answer as correct since it maps to the question better, but I am going to use your solution so I am honestly not sure. What is the etiquette here?

Comment: @JakeRankin whatever answer you think would best help someone that has come to this question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saving it in form, you can directly do this operation in view. For example:

```
def manageclient(request, urlid):
    client = Client.objects.get(id=urlid)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AssignManagerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            client.assigned_manager = form.cleaned_data['full_name']
            client.save()
            return render(request, 'mysite/manageclient.html', {})
```

Comment: Ah interesting, thank you! Is it a problem that 'full_name' is not a real field? Should I instead send the primary key or something instead?

Comment: If it works as implemented, then its fine. As long as it is correctly assigning assigned_manager value

Comment: I just tried and it does not seem to be working, although I get no error. After submitting the form the form weidget disapears, and after refreshing the page (where I print out the assigned_manager field) it shows nothing.

Comment: @IainShelvington is right btw, in the form, it is rendering Clients, not managers. Now, if you want to assign `Manager` to `Client`, then you need to update the form's queryset to `queryset=Manager.objects.all()`